# how to set an instance variable from a class method?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I am trying to do a custom active record macro. But it right now seems impossible set an instance variable from within it's block.. here is what i am trying to do.

```
module ActiveRecord
   class Base
      def self.included(base)
         base.class.send(:define_method, :my_macro) do |args|
            # instance_variable_set for the model instance that has called this 
            # macro using args
         end
      end
   end
end
```

i have tried class_eval, instance_eval.. but nothing seems to work or i don't how to use them.

Thanks in advance.

**Edit**: Let me try to explain better. I have a class method. An instance of the class calls this method. Now, this class method should instruct the instance to set an instance variable for itself.

**Edit- this is how i want o use the macro**

```
class MyModel < ActiveRecord::Base
   my_macro(*args)
   def after_initialize
      # use the value set in the macro as @instance variable
   end
end
```

Comment: Um... unless Ruby redefined the term "class method", the point of a class method is that there is no instance?

Comment: That's what I was thinking too. I'm interested in seeing if there is a way of telling an instance how to add its own instance variable dynamically.

Comment: @greg, @delnan : yes.. i completely agree... but i am wondering if there is a way for the class to tell it's instance to add an instance variable to itself.

Comment: @delnan In ruby, a class is an object too, so it can have instance variables. :P

Comment: @Josiah: Yes (in Python too), but I don't think that anyone calls these instance variables ;) Rather class/static variables.

Comment: Do you basically want to tie into the initialization process of ActiveRecord::Base?

Comment: yes.. i want to add a macro accessible to all models. the macro has to set an instance for the class's instance that has called it

Comment: please check the edit. is it possible to send the class instance in the my_macro(*args) call?

Comment: How about trying the after_initialize callback? http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html

Comment: Just saw your edit#2. Maybe in #after_initialize you can do MyModel.class_eval{@my_macro} to retrieve the value, and then use instance_varaible_set for the instance of MyModel.

Comment: yeah.. this is what i have been doing till now. but what i am trying is setting a default value while i create an attr_accessor from the macro itself.

Comment: i am trying to see if it is possible?

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are thinking of:

```
class DynamicAdd
  def add_method
    self.class_eval do
      attr_accessor :some_method
    end
  end
end
```

You can then do the following:

```
k = DynamicAdd.new
k.some_method = "hi"
```

should result in an undefined method error.

But,

```
k = DynamicAdd.new
k.add_method
k.some_method = "hi"
```

should work.

You can use this same format to define other types of methods besides attr_accessors as well:

```
class DynamicAdd
  def add_method
    self.class_eval do
      def some_method
        return "hi"
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Your `add_method` is a regular method, not a class method like the OP was asking for.

Comment: I think OP was asking for a dynamic way to tell an instance to add an instance variable:"yes.. i completely agree... but i am wondering if there is a way for the class to tell it's instance to add an instance variable to itself"

Answer (score 0):

Hm.. Isn't included() a Module method? I don't think you can use that in a class like you have written.  If you want to create a class method you can do

```
class Base
  def self.my_method
  end
```

or

```
class Base
  class << self
    def my_method
    end
  end
```

If all you want to do is to add an instance variable to an existing object, then you can use #instance_variable_set

```
class Base
  class << self
    def my_method(instance_of_base, value)
      instance_of_base.instance_variable_set "@x", value
    end
  end
end

a = Base.new
a.class.send(:my_method, *[a,4])
```

Comment: you are right. but i don't want to send the method every time i instantiate it. i want it to be automatic. hence a macro. is it possible to send the class's instance as argument to the macro method?